# Pass security token WCF

Tags: .net, wcf

I have client and server. They are running on different credentials.

How do I get security **TOKEN** on client side, pass this **TOKEN** to server side and impersonate user there?

It would be very HELPFULL if you could provide simple code example to to **get, send and recieve token.**

I am only interested in solution with a security tokens, please.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you attempted? What have you researched? Please demonstrate that you've made some effort to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

[Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088.aspx) is only possible with Windows accounts. It also usually requires Windows domain (and domain accounts) and for some operations (delegation) also Kerberos.